# Selected item color is not working properly on flutter

Tags: android, flutter

So guys I am working on this navigation bar and when I tap one of the two items it doesn't change the color of the item, any idea why? here's the code for the navigation bar:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title'])),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        onTap: _selectPage,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            label: "Category",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            label: "Favorites",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting the second item to change it's color from white to my secondary color but instead when I tapped on it, it still gave me white color

Comment: add currentIndex https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/currentIndex.html